# distributing a fixed number of things into M*N grid

Tags: c, arrays

Suppose, there is a M*N (M=row,N=column) array and a total of MN computers (each has an id from 1 to MN). I have to **randomly** distribute the MN computers in each cell of M*N array so that each cell has one computer. How will I do this?

sample code fragment:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define M 10
#define N 10
int main()
{
    int A[M][N];
    int p=M*N;  //total number of computers
   //what to do here
}
```

what additional things will I have to add to the previous code to get the result I stated above?

Comment: Use `rand` and `srand` function.

Comment: There is no difference between randomly placing computers in a grid and randomly placing them in a row.

Comment: Use a (pseudo) random number generator and maintain an array of selected items. In each step you generate a random number *r*, choose the *r*:th non-selected item and mark it as selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rand` and `srand` functions.
Example of use:

```
/* initialize random seed: */
srand (time(NULL));
/* generate secret number between 1 and 10: */
randomNumber = rand() % 10 + 1;
```

You can check out references for rand [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) and srand [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.  But, you have to ensure that placement is unique, all computers get placed, and all slots get filled [once]

Assume A is static/global (e.g. it's all zeroes).

Note: rand() is from stdlib.h but it takes no arguments.  So:

```
#define xrand(_lim) (rand() % _lim)
```

Also, since M and N are #defines, I'd do `#define P (M * N)`

Simple and slow:

```
void
place(void)
{
    int compid;
    int y;
    int x;

    for (compid = 1;  compid <= P;  ++compid) {
        while (1) {
            y = xrand(M);
            x = xrand(N);
            if (A[y][x] == 0) {
                A[y][x] = compid;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An alternate way:

```
int used[P + 1];

void
place(void)
{
    int compid;
    int y;
    int x;

    for (y = 0;  y < M;  ++y) {
        for (x = 0;  x < N;  ++x) {
            while (1) {
                compid = xrand(P);

                // we want 1..P not 0..P-1
                compid += 1;
                if (compid > P)
                    continue

                if (used[compid] == 0) {
                    A[y][x] = compid;
                    used[compid] = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```